# Using the sharing intent in a "fluid way"

Tags: android, android-intent, share

### background

many times, we wish to allow the user to share something on android apps.

this can be done using the next function:

> ```
> public static Intent prepareSharingIntent() {
>   final List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
>   final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>   final Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
>   targetedShareIntents.add(smsIntent);
>   shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
>   smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
>   final String invitationMessage = "check out my App!";
>   smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, invitationMessage);
>   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, invitationMessage);
>   shareIntent.putExtra("sms_body", invitationMessage);
>   smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", invitationMessage);
>   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out this app!");
>   smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out this app!");
>   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
>   final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share using...");
>   chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
>           | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
>   return chooserIntent;
> }
> ```

### problem

some users (like me) have a lot of apps that can handle the sharing intent.

this means that sometimes there is a long delay (can be a second or even more on some cases) from the time i click to share something, to the time that the dialog is shown, so this is quite an undesirable behavior.

i have my patience, but maybe some users will think the app is "laggy" because of this.

in fact, i've noticed that this issue occurs on many apps (including the play store app). the user doesn't get a feedback that the device currently does something to show the dialog .

### question

what can be done in order to make it look more fluid , or at least show some progress dialog till the real dialog is shown?

Comment: Did you ever get around to fixing this?

Comment: @DavidMurdoch I've created a dialog of my own.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: You put your prepareSharingIntent() code within an AsyncTask and start that task when the app starts up. You can then hold a global reference to the 'chooserIntent' (e.g. in the Application class) and show it once the reference is not null and the user clicks on the share button.

Make sure to run it at low priority so you don't slow down your apps startup:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        chooserIntent = prepareSharingIntent();
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) { }
}
```

Comment: could've been a good solution, but i think the main reason for the delay is not the creation of the intent that takes so much time. it's the chooser dialog that is shown for it. the function i've just shown takes 2-3 ms to finish...

Comment: I was under the impression that your function takes all the time. Since that is not the case, I only can think of ugly hacks like: start the activity in the AsyncTask, but immediately finish() it (... you could do this in 'onPause()' of your activities, since you can't customize the share Activity). My guess is, that the share activity is cached afterwards.

Comment: you mean i should create a new activity that just shows a progress bar? but if i finish it when the dialog is show, the dialog will be closed too. about the asyncTask, i don't understand why you still think it's needed, since the task takes a very short time.

Comment: No progress bar, I mean this: You startActivity(chooserIntent) within the AsyncTask right away. Isn't this what takes a long time? Then, when android starts to display the activity, your app looses control, thus 'onPause()' should be called. at this point, you finish() the just started Activity (this might be tricky :). 

basically, the idea is to force the system to create the activity right away, and then when it's used later on, it should be faster to create.

Comment: i still don't understand. the startActivity starts something that belongs to android- the dialog that shows the user the choices of which app to use. still i also don't understand why i need asyncTask. all of the operations here take a very short time. it's only when the operation of showing the dialog has started that it has delay, during which the user doesn't see anything.